# Showing that $Z_p$ is a discrete evaluation ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Prove that for $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ prime, $\mathbb{Z}_p= \{ \alpha \in \mathbb{Q} | \alpha = \frac{a}{b},$ a and b integers such that p does not divide b $\}$ is a DVR.

##### Definitions:

> 1. R is a local Noetherian ring such that its maximal ideal is principal.
> 2. There exists an irreducible element $t \in R$ such that every element $r \in R - \{0\}$ can be written uniquely in the form $r=ut^m$ with $u \in R^{\times}$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

##### Attempt:

In order to understand the DVR better, I would like to prove it using 1 and again using 2.

For 1) I need that R is local Noetherian ring. But to be Noetherian, R has to be finitely generated, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not. Doesn't this mean that $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is either Noetherian? Then I want to find a maximal ideal that contains all the elements that are not units, right?

For 2) would I want $t$ to be 1 or $a$? And I am rather stuck after this. I think I am fine with uniqueness though.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659853/localization-of-r-kx-y-y2-x2-x-is-a-dvr?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But to be Noetherian, R has to be finitely generated, and Q is not.

That depends on what module we're referring to. Q is certainly not finitely generated by Z, but it is finitely generated by Q.

The bigger issue is that we are not talking about either of these: we are talking about a subring R of Q. If it is to be Noetherian, its ideals will all be finitely generated as modules over R. You are describing the localization of Z at the (complement of) the prime ideal (p). Localizations of commutative Noetherian rings are also commutative. This can be proven by using facts relating the ideals of the two rings.

> Then I want to find a maximal ideal that contains all the elements that are not units, right?

Sure, and that ideal is obvious, right? Which fractions can't you "flip over" to get their inverses?

*For 2) would I want t to be 1 or a?* if t were 1, every element would be a unit and you would be looking at a field. And $a$ is not a fixed element of the ring, so that is just an invalid choice. Isn't there a more obvious candidate, an important fellow generating the unique maximal ideal?

Comment: So for 2) we would want t to be p? Then I would want that for $\alpha = \frac{a}{b} = ut^m$. And since the only non-units are of the form $\frac{b}{a}$, I would have \frac{a}{b} *p^m?

Comment: @math1234567 The first sentence is right, but the last sentence isn't clear. Supposing $\frac{a}{b}$ is a unit in the ring, that means that $\frac{b}{a}$ is in the ring too, and for that to happen, $p$ can't divide $a$. Suppose $q$ is some prime besides $p$. Is $q$ a unit in this ring?

Comment: What I am confused is, how is module theory coming in explaining DVRS?

Comment: what you meant by this "not a fixed element of the ring"

Comment: *how is module theory coming in explaining DVRS?* I don't know exactly what you mean, but the definitions of "finitely generated" and "Noetherian" here are module theoretic in nature.  That's the only module theory needed...

Comment: *what you meant by this "not a fixed element of the ring"*  The only $a$ that appears is in the notation for $\mathbb Z_p$, where it describes "an integer."  So later when the poster asks "to be $1$ or $a$?" I pointed out that $a$ isn't just a single ("fixed"/"concrete") element, it is ranging over all the integers in that notation.  It's highly probable they meant something else but it was the best I could do at the time.